# D3.js get unexpected transition effect

Tags: d3.js, transition

I'd like to implement [mbostock's path transition tutorial](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/) in d3.js v4. but got non continous transition effect which is unexpected.

After hours of trials and play, still can not figure out what's wrong...

how can one get continuous transitions, why the code below won't work as expected?

I scheduled as transitions as follows:

```js
var transition = d3.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .ease(d3.easeLinear);

transition.on('start', tick)

function tick() {
    // update the domains
    now = new Date();
    x.domain([now - (n - 2) * duration, now - duration]);
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data)]);

    // push the accumulated count onto the back, and reset the count
    data.push(Math.min(30, count));
    count = 0;

    // redraw the line
    svg.select(".line")
      .attr("d", line)
      .attr("transform", null)


    // slide the x-axis left
    axis.transition(transition).call(x.axis) 

    // slide the line left
    path.transition(transition)
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(now - (n - 1) * duration) + ", 0)")

    d3.active(this).transition(transition).on('start', tick) 

    // pop the old data point off the front
    data.shift();
  }
```

the full code is here:

http://codepen.io/reverland/pen/QdeEOO?editors=1010

Comment: You can define the transition inside `tick()`: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LWPEjN?editors=0010

Comment: thanks @GerardoFurtado , can you explain why you put transition inside tick? it looks the line and axis do not transit synchronously now.

Comment: This is not a solution, that's why I wrote it as a comment. That's just to show you why you had the stuttering. For a proper solution, you'll have to refactor your code.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I finnally got this working well, but still a confused with why I should use another transition inside tick, can't I schedule everything in one transition?
why I had the stuttering?